# an error of running a SQL query from cursor.execute in pyodbc of python 3.2.5 onm win 7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, python-3.x, windows-7, pyodbc

I am working on pyodbc in Eclipse (4.3.2v20140221-1852) with PyDev on Win 7. My python is 3.2.5.

At my code:

```
 cursor.execute("select top " + str(1) + " a.my_id, a.mycode" + 
               "from my_table as a where a.mycode = ?", aGivenCode)
```

I got an error :

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Why I got error at " as a " ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple suggestions for future development:

1. Use multi-line string notation `"""` to allow better identification of syntax errors (like the missing space between column and table in the original query).
2. Instead of string concatenation, use a parameter for `TOP` values. The value must be wrapped in parentheses.

With these guidelines, your original code would be updated to:

```
top = 1
cursor.execute("""select top (?) a.my_id, a.mycode
                  from my_table as a
                  where a.mycode = ?""",
               (top, aGivenCode))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this? I think you're missing a space in there:

```
cursor.execute("select top " + str(1) + " a.my_id, a.mycode from my_table as a where a.mycode = ?", aGivenCode)
```

See how there is no space in between 'a.mycode' and 'from my_table'? I'm not 100% sure that is right, but give it a try.

These things are also easier to debug like this:

```
sql = "select top " + str(1) + " a.my_id, a.mycode from my_table as a where a.mycode = ?"
print sql
cursor.execute(sql, aGivenCode)
```